# how to add a Scroll bar for a partial view rendered inside a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have the following Script and markup to render a partial view inside a modal popup:-

```
  $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {        
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');

                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but can i force the modal window to show a vertical scroll bar , if the partial view content exceed certain height ?

Answer (score 1):

- Set a **max-height** property on your modal window to prevent it from
  exceeding a certain height.
- Then set **overflow-y: auto** on your modal window to have a vertical scroll bar pop up if the content exceeds the height.
- To force the vertical scroll bar to show up regardless of whether the content overflows, set it to **overflow-y: scroll** instead.

Comment: but I am not sure how I can apply these settings inside my script, I tried passing these values inside the ").modal({" same as for the keyboard:true but it did not work

Comment: You can use jquery to set css by doing something like `$('#myModal').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');`

Comment: I tried the following " $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show').css('overflow-y', 'scroll').css('max-height', '10');" but it did not have any effect on the modal